# Console not defined when I specifically check for its existence

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm writing a quick log function to wrap around the native `console.log` to prevent errors later on in development (like forgotten `console.log` statements in your code).  I'm using the mootools [`$defined`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Core/Core#defined) and [`$type`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Core/Core#type) functions to check for the existence of a console and the console.log function before calling it.  However when I disable firebug I get the following error in firefox.

> Error: console is not defined
>   Source File: http://diagnostic.localhost/js/emp.custom.js 
>   Line: 6

```
EMP.log = function() {
 if (DEBUG && $defined(console) && $type(console.log) == 'function') { //line 6
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); //turn arguments into array
  console.log.pass(args);
 }
}
```

It seems like using `$defined` should eliminate this error, so does anyone have any ideas as to what the issue may be?

I'm using mootools v1.2.3.

EDIT: I've tried the following and they also give them same error:

```
if (DEBUG && $type(console) == "object" && $type(console.log) == 'function') {

if (DEBUG && $chk(console) && $type(console.log) == 'function') {
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `$defined(window.console)` instead. If Firefox goes through the scope chain and can't find a variable, it'll throw an error, but if you're explicit with the context where you're looking for a variable, it'll give you `undefined`.

Comment: Nice! Glad you've figured it out :)

Comment: Good tip! If you're not using a toolkit, you can still fix this problem by checking for `window.console == undefined` instead of `console == undefined`.